# How to solve "ValueError: `window_shape` is incompatible with `arr_in.shape` "?

Tags: python, image-processing, mask, tiff, semantic-segmentation

I tried to patch the big  .tif images by using patchify library. I followed the https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IL7LKSLb9I&ab_channel=DigitalSreeni video and I got this code from this .
I got the following error.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "generate.py", line 13, in
>
> patches_img = patchify(large_image, (256, 256), step=256)  # Step=256 for 256 patches means no overlap   File
> "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\patchify_*init*_.py",
> l ine 32, in patchify
> return view_as_windows(image, patch_size, step)   File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\patchify\view_as_windows
> .py", line 28, in view_as_windows
> raise ValueError("`window_shape` is incompatible with `arr_in.shape`") ValueError: `window_shape` is incompatible with
> `arr_in.shape`

The Code is below mentioned

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from patchify import patchify
import tifffile as tiff

large_image_stack = tiff.imread('C:\\Users\\HP\\Downloads\\Radar_data\\test\\images\\2018_09_26.tif')
large_mask_stack = tiff.imread('C:\\Users\\HP\\Downloads\\Radar_data\\test\\masks\\2018_12_19_d.tif')

for img in range(large_image_stack.shape[0]):

    large_image = large_image_stack[img]

    patches_img = patchify(large_image, (256, 256), step=256)  # Step=256 for 256 patches means no overlap

    for i in range(patches_img.shape[0]):
        for j in range(patches_img.shape[1]):
            single_patch_img = patches_img[i, j, :, :]
            tiff.imwrite('patches/images/' + 'image_' + str(img) + '_' + str(i) + str(j) + ".tif", single_patch_img)

for msk in range(large_mask_stack.shape[0]):

    large_mask = large_mask_stack[msk]

    patches_mask = patchify(large_mask, (256, 256), step=256)  # Step=256 for 256 patches means no overlap

    for i in range(patches_mask.shape[0]):
        for j in range(patches_mask.shape[1]):
            single_patch_mask = patches_mask[i, j, :, :]
            tiff.imwrite('patches/masks/' + 'mask_' + str(msk) + '_' + str(i) + str(j) + ".tif", single_patch_mask)
            single_patch_mask = single_patch_mask / 255.
```

I am a new one for this area and hope anyone will help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This code simply does not work if:

1- the loaded image is an RGB image (with a third dimension=3), so need to consider in the patch size:
patches_img = patchify(large_image, (256, 256,**3**), step=256)

and

single_patch_img=img_patches[i,j,:,:,**:**]

2- or the original image is not a stack of images (need to remove the first loop)

more insight in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68224588/problem-when-using-patchify-library-to-create-patches).