# Dividing images into patches

Tags: python, image-processing

i would like  to  practise with library of  patchify in order to learn how to  divide image  into  several patches, for this , i found  following  site  : [image into patches](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-split-an-image-into-patches-with-python-e1cf42cf4f77)

also i have download sample image  , which is given here :
[image: ocean image]

dimension of this image is  612 X 408, so  on the  based of  site, i have applied code  and got  the following error :

> raise ValueError("`window_shape` is incompatible with `arr_in.shape`")
> ValueError: `window_shape` is incompatible with `arr_in.shape`

the code is given here :

```
`import numpy as np
from patchify import patchify
from PIL import Image
import cv2
#ocean =Image.open("ocean.jpg") #612 X 408
ocean =cv2.imread("ocean.jpg")
print(ocean.size)
ocean = np.asarray(ocean)
patches =patchify(ocean,(306,204),2)
print(patches.shape)
for i in range(patches.shape[0]):
    for j in range(patches.shape[1]):
        patch = patches[i, j]
        patch = Image.fromarray(patch)
        num = i * patches.shape[1] + j
        patch.save(f"patch_{num}.jpg")`
```

so my question is how  can determine window shape? i used   (306,204) because  it is  simple half of the original image's shape, is  there any  rule  of choosing  window shape?when i  searched about this  problem, i found following solution

[possible solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69295396/how-to-solve-valueerror-window-shape-is-incompatible-with-arr-in-shape)

on this link there  was given such  suggestion :

> **or the original image is not a stack of images (need to remove the first loop) **

if  i  will remove outer loop, then how can i go through  whole image? please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have to follow the documentation.

- > image is a NumPy array ... or (image_height, image_width, N) for N-channels images (**3 if RGB**).
- > patch_shape is the shape of each patch, ... or (**patch_height**, **patch_width**, **N**)
- > step defines the distance between one patch... If step ≥ patch_height there is no overlap between patches in the same row...

Assuming we want to divide the image into 2x2 patches use:

```
patches = patchify(ocean, (204, 306, 3), 204)
```

Note:
Since the patches are not squares, there is an overlap in the horizontal axis.
It looks like patchify is intended to be used for patches with some ovelap.

---

Other issues:

- In OpenCV the order of the color channels is BGR and in PIL the order is RGB.
  We should try not to load an image using OpenCV and save it with PIL.
- Use `patch = patches[i, j, 0]` as in the documentation instead of `patch = patches[i, j]`.

---

Code sample:

```
import numpy as np
from patchify import patchify
from PIL import Image
import cv2
ocean = np.array(Image.open("ocean.jpg")) #612 X 408
#ocean =cv2.imread("ocean.jpg")
print(ocean.shape)
ocean = np.asarray(ocean)
patches = patchify(ocean, (204, 306, 3), 204)
print(patches.shape)
for i in range(patches.shape[0]):
    for j in range(patches.shape[1]):
        patch = patches[i, j, 0]
        patch = Image.fromarray(patch)
        num = i * patches.shape[1] + j
        patch.save(f"patch_{num}.jpg")
```

---

[image]   [image]

[image]   [image]