# Using patchify to create patches from images with different shapes

Tags: python, image, image-processing

I use patchify to generate patches from images. My folder, from which I take the data base, contains images which are of different shape (1536x2048 and 2048x1536).

- If I use only one shape (no matter if 1536x2048 or 2048x1536) I get the reasonable number of patches.
- But if I combine both shapes, I get some additional images, which are just duplicates of patches.

Why does my code not work when I use two different shapes, even though they should both produce even numbers in the number of resulting patches for both axes?

The core of my code comes from the following question (before this code, I just create lists with the corresponding information about the images I'm using):
[Problem when using patchify library to create patches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68224588/problem-when-using-patchify-library-to-create-patches)

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from PIL import Image
import os
from patchify import patchify
       
List = []

destinationFile = "C:/.../Output/Images/"


for root, Lists, files in os.walk("C:/.../Input/Images/"):
    for name in files:
        if name.endswith(".png"):
            List.append(os.path.join(root, name))


            for filename in List:
                img_no_ndarray = Image.open(filename)
                img = np.array(img_no_ndarray)
                patches_img = patchify(img, (512, 512, 3), step=512)

                for i in range(patches_img.shape[0]):
                    for j in range(patches_img.shape[1]):
                        single_patch_img = patches_img[i, j, 0, :, :, :]
                        if not cv2.imwrite(destinationFile + str(i) + "_" + str(j) + "_" + name, single_patch_img):
                            raise Exception("Could not write the image")
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Two thoughts, if it works when all input has the same dimensions then have you tried adding a reshaping step to match all input shapes before running through patchify?

And, you might find that this line is better for avoiding duplications/overwriting your output patches:

```
    cv2.imwrite(r'C:/destinationfilepath/image_{}{}.png'.format(str(i).zfill(4),str(j).zfill(4)), single_patch_img)
```